# JavaScript - element .offsetLeft & .offsetTop - Sporadic Values

Tags: javascript, offset

I'm trying to setup a simple drag and drop interface but am having trouble due to inconsistent element offset values. The element's offset is derived within a `mousemove` event. The values will alternate between correct and incorrect. I'm stumped!
It kinda looks like the element/div is flopping around lol
I really have no idea why `div.offsetLeft` & `div.offsetTop` will alternate between correct and incorrect values with every `mousemove`. Any ideas and/or suggestion would be much appreciated!

---

jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qemX6/1/)

ps, Click on the div by one of it's corners and move it around to seewhat I mean to it's fullest

---

```
* {
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
    outline:    none;
}
#pageWrap {
    position:   relative;
    width:      1024px;
    margin:     0 auto;
}
#div {
    position:   absolute;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    background: #000;
    overflow:   hidden;
}
```

---

```
<div id="pageWrap">
    <div id="div" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
var div         = document.getElementById('div'),
    divWidth    = div.clientWidth,
    divHeight   = div.clientHeight,
    divStyle    = div.style,
    pageWrap    = document.getElementById('pageWrap');

function divMove(e) {
    var mouseLeft   = e.clientX - pageWrap.offsetLeft,
        mouseTop    = e.clientY - pageWrap.offsetTop,
        divLeft     = mouseLeft - (div.offsetLeft + divWidth - mouseLeft),
        divTop      = mouseTop - (div.offsetTop + divHeight - mouseTop);

        divStyle.left   = divLeft + 'px';
        divStyle.top    = divTop + 'px';
    }

function divDown(e) {
    if(e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    if (e.target === div) {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, false);
    }
}

function cleanUp() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, false);
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', divDown, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', cleanUp, false);
```

---

Comment: i assume, that you want to keep the distance between the top, left corner of the div to the mouse cursor while dragging right? if yes then they way you try would not work. values are not alternating between correct and incorrect (event it would look like). the effect you see is that the center of the div _flips_ around the cursor. you need to store the distance between left/top and the cursor on mouse down, and use this distance on mouse move to update the div position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qemX6/2/.

When you start draggin you need to remember the distance from the boundaries of div to mouse. That's done in `x` and `y`. (just like `e.clientX - div.offsetLeft`)

Then you just give your `div` position of `mousePoistion + rememberedOffset`.

Comment: I spent all night tinkering with this... I feel like a bit of an oaf right now but whatev. Appreciate the fiddle. Thank You!